# QField Drop Down Menu

Tags: qfield

Unable to locate "Package for QField" in the drop down menu. (See pic below)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short tour for more about how the site works. https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

The QField Sync is a plugin. You can install by going to plugins --> Manage and install plugins, search for qfield and click on install it. In version 3.x the Package for QField is available. Consider update since Brighton 2.6 is from 2014 and will not be updated anymore.

[image]

Comment: I have QField Sync installed, it is not giving me the options for "packaging" as it did before.

Comment: I edited my answer, if you still use 2.6.1 Brighton, consider to update your QGIS since that version won't be updated anymore.